# Is my \date broken?

Tags: xetex, datetime, scrbook, isodate

When using `\date{}`, I get this weird result:

[image]
*(I've blurred out some parts, since they're, well, sensitive for me)*

Why is it doing this?

I'm using `isodate`, but it's not the issue, I've commented it out, and it's still doing those weird numbers.

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile my documents.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem

Comment: Plus I think `\date{}` only sets the `@date`. It does not display it.  Something else is producing the number.  If you are trying to get today's date use `\today`.

Comment: What is contained within `general.teh`, since I'm unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps better, what does `\show\date` deliver to your terminal. It should be `\date=macro: #1->\gdef\@date{#1}`. If not, I'm assuming `general.teh` is the culprit.

Comment: To me it looks like a font problem. Either because the oldstyle numbers in the font used are broken or because the font exists in two version on the system an xetex gets confused.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You might be on to something, The problem only occurs, when I use "Linux Libertine O" with `fontspec`. When I switch to another font face, it's OK. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Put `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` in your document and compile on the command line with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" filename`. Then compare the pathes in the log and in the terminal to find out which font you have double. Remove one version.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Awesome! You were right! I had two versions of Linux Biolinum O installed. One was in the system, one was in my local `.fonts` folder. Please make an answer, I'll accept it right away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it looks like a font problem. Either because the oldstyle numbers in the font used are broken or because the font exists in two version on the system and xetex gets confused.

Put `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` in your document and compile on the command line with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"` filename. Then compare the pathes in the log and in the terminal to find out which font you have double. Remove one version.